# Error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, google-maps, typeerror, python-webbrowser

I'm doing a vocal assistant in Python 3.8 and I use a maps url to create an itinerary.
The problem is that I have an error and I have no idea how to fix it:
this is my code

```
def RecordAudio(ask = False):
    print("micro on")
    voice_data = ''
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        if ask:
            print(ask)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN")
            print(voice_data)
            respond(voice_data)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            if "" in voice_data.lower():
                RecordAudio()
            else:
                print("Sorry, I did not understand, could you repeat ?")
                RecordAudio()
        except sr.RequestError:
            print("I can't answer for the moment")

def respond(voice_data):
    if "itineraire" in voice_data:
        frommaps = RecordAudio('Where do you go from?')
        tomaps = RecordAudio("Where do you go to?")
        print("Calculating...")
        time.sleep(1)
        itineraireurl = "https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/" +frommaps +'/'+tomaps
        webbrowser.get().open(itineraireurl)
```

And the error

```
  File "main.py", line 86, in respond
    itineraireurl = "https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/" +frommaps +'/'+tomaps
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: Check if your variables *from* and *to* is null/ ie not defined or something like that

Comment: No, there is no problemsin the code, the variables are all defined and that's why I don't understand.

Comment: Oh damn, it was my bad, that thing you are trying to concat, what is it type?? In python compiler do type(from) and tell me what's that it , most likely I suspect you trying to concat non string variables to string variables?

Comment: A variable can be defined and still have the value None

Comment: I just change the code, i didn't see that "from" is already used for python. I changed "from" into "frommaps"

Comment: @Agent_Orange I've got this `<class 'NoneType'>` is it what did you except ?

Comment: Well yea, *from* is reserved variable, but I'd expect some different error if that was case, anyways, looks like I have to check on this one now

Comment: Where is `RecordAudio` defined?  Is it a function (or class) you have written, or does it come from a library?

Comment: How could the error mention `tompas` if you used `tomaps`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward it's a function i've created (using speech recognition)

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks for your comment (I didn't noticed that error: I change variable name because they were in french so i prefered to change language for stack overflow and i made a typing error when i changed the name in console)

Comment: If the `RecordAudio` function is one that you have written, then it is likely that it is where the problem is.  It looks like you are expecting it to return a string, but it is actually returning `None`.  If you still need help tracking down the problem please edit your question to include the definition of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
itineraireurl = "https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/" +frommaps +'/'+tomaps
    webbrowser.get().open(itineraireurl)
```

Put above line of code in form of string like below:

```
itineraireurl = f"https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/ {frommaps} +'/'+tomaps.webbrowser.get().open(itineraireurl)"
```

PS : Try to use python f string.